# Keycloak should be deployed as a separate microservice, what does it mean?

Tags: deployment, microservices, keycloak, keycloak-services

What can it be for, what logic can be there?
I suppose there should be a connection to keycloak, maybe checking access to create roles and users, am I right or wrong?

Comment: _Keycloak is an open source Identity and Access Management solution aimed at modern applications and services._ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_management

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may mean that you need to deploy Keycloak in its own container, separate from the apps.